# Ruby read bytes/hex from socket, how to?

Tags: ruby, sockets, networking

How can I read bytes/hex from socket in ruby? All the sockets read methods return strings. 
Does any one return direct bytes? Or have any options to return the bytes/hex instead of strings?

I know I can convert, but, for performance reasons I want to get the raw data from socket.

Comment: A String in a binary encoding *is* just a bunch of bytes.

Comment: As far as I know, Ruby does not have a byte class. I would recommend that you use `pack` or `unpack`. In my experience, they also have quite good performance.